# How to group data by hour of the day in mysql when there are multiple timestamps?

Tags: mysql, sql, time, timestamp

I have a dataset where each record has multiple timestamps. I am trying to summarize the dataset to get counts of each timestamp by absolute hour of the day.

I am able to perform grouping by hour when there is only one timestamp but unable to do this when I have multiple timestamps.

My current data:

```
MemberID    Appointment_Time    CheckIn_Time    CheckOut_Time
1           12:20pm             01:30pm         05:00pm
2           09:00am             08:30am         04:20pm
3           12:10pm             03:30pm         05:20pm
```

What I want

```
Hour of the day #Appts  #CheckIns    #Checkouts
8                  0       1            0
9                  1       0            0
10                 0       0            0
11                 0       0            0
12                 2       0            0
1                  0       1            0
2                  0       0            0
3                  0       1            0
4                  0       0            1
5                  0       0            2
```

Comment: Are you actually storing the text `12:20pm` in your table?

Comment: The time is stored as a timestamp in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use conditional aggregation (`HOUR` function assumes that you're using a date/datetime column):

```
SELECT hourlist.hh hour_of_day
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN HOUR(Appointment_Time) = hourlist.hh THEN 1 END) appts
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN HOUR(CheckIn_Time) = hourlist.hh THEN 1 END) checkins
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN HOUR(CheckOut_Time) = hourlist.hh THEN 1 END) checkouts
FROM (
    SELECT 0 AS hh UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 UNION ALL
    SELECT 8 UNION ALL
    SELECT 9 UNION ALL
    SELECT 10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 11 UNION ALL
    SELECT 12 UNION ALL
    SELECT 13 UNION ALL
    SELECT 14 UNION ALL
    SELECT 15 UNION ALL
    SELECT 16 UNION ALL
    SELECT 17 UNION ALL
    SELECT 18 UNION ALL
    SELECT 19 UNION ALL
    SELECT 20 UNION ALL
    SELECT 21 UNION ALL
    SELECT 22 UNION ALL
    SELECT 23
) AS hourlist
LEFT JOIN appointments ON hourlist.hh IN (HOUR(Appointment_Time), HOUR(CheckIn_Time), HOUR(CheckOut_Time))
GROUP BY hourlist.hh
```